# adobe native extension for android, app crashes on back button when trying to come back from Browser

Tags: android, crash, adobe, air-native-extension

I have created a native extension (Android) for 3rd party advertiser (TrialPay), in which it requires to load webview and further opens the url in native browser. After that it asks to tap back button so that user can come back to app from native browser but at that moment app crashes...

here is my Activity in native extension code :

```
public class TrialPayOfferWallActivity extends Activity{

Button doneButton = null;
WebView offerWallWebView = null;
public static FREContext freContext;
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside TrialPayOfferWallActivity OnCreate function");

    this.setContentView(freContext.getResourceId("layout.trialpayofferwallactivity"));

    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "1");
    Bundle extraBundleObj = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "2");
    String urlString = extraBundleObj.getString("urlString");
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "3-"+urlString);

    doneButton = (Button) this.findViewById(freContext.getResourceId("id.btnDone"));
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "4");
    offerWallWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(freContext.getResourceId("id.offerwallwebview"));
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "5");
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              setResult(RESULT_OK);
              finish();
          }
        });
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "6");
    offerWallWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    offerWallWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    offerWallWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    offerWallWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "7");
    this.loadWebViewWithURL(urlString);
}

public void loadWebViewWithURL(String url2)
{
    offerWallWebView.loadUrl(url2);
    offerWallWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            if (url.startsWith("tpbow")) {
                url = url.substring(5);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );
        }
        return true;
    }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && (offerWallWebView.getVisibility() == WebView.VISIBLE)) {
    this.goBack(keyCode, event);
    return true;
 } else {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}

private void goBack(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (offerWallWebView.canGoBack()) {
    offerWallWebView.goBack();
 } else {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    //sendErrorBack("Cancelled");
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPause");
}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    //sendErrorBack("Cancelled");
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStop");
}

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume");
}

protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStart");
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside OnActivityResult function");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Inside OnActivityResult function->result ok");
    }

}
```

}

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: null pointer exception while creating the same activity when it try to reload app after back pressing back button on Browser...